# Requirement for a suggested edit to be a minimum number of characters can be restrictive

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Is there a compelling reason for there to be any minimum number of characters for a suggested edit? 
For a quick typo correction this can be slightly frustrating and encourages fluff to be added in order to meet the character limit.

Comment: There's no minimum number of characters restriction for an **edit**. There is one for a **suggested edit**. Once you got enough reputation, you can fix typos at will.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a compelling reason for the minimum character count. Your suggested edits are going to go into a review queue. If minor edits were allowed, the queue would be quickly clogged up with one-character spelling corrections.

Make the edit count instead. Don't waste reviewers time with a minor change that, in the big scheme of things, doesn't really matter. Fix everything in the post instead. Improve grammar, spelling, formatting, remove fluff. Then submit.

Or get yourself to 2000 points and earn the right to edit outright without your edit having to be reviewed. Then you can make minor edits too. Take into account however that edits bump a post up on the 'active questions' listings, so do try to make an edit count *anyway*, so as not to take attention away from more deserving posts.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow: no, the assumption rules should be worked around rather than understood is creating fluff. Suggested edit reviewers can and should reject such fluff.

Comment: We don't need more people to help out; the queue is working fine. If anything, we have too many reviewers at the moment, with robo-reviewers working for badges being a notable problem. Syntax errors in code with suggested edits are *difficult* to review because they require subject knowledge; I have enough work keeping out well-meaning edits from mucking up my answers as it is.

Comment: And where in the dupe do you get the impression minor changes should be approved? Note that you also get reputation for accepted suggested edits; if minor edits are routinely accepted, what is to stop rep hunters from making *multiple minor edits* just to increase the reputation gain, per post?